# How to produce multiple lists of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I use the `glossaries` package to produce a list of acronyms and also a glossary of gene names that I want to keep separated from other abbreviations.

I use e.g. `\newacronym{SNP}{SNP}{single nucleotide polymorphism}` to create acronyms and something like `\newglossaryentry{ApoE}{type=gene,name=ApoE, description={apolipoprotein E}}` to define genes. This allows me to print the list of acronyms and the list of genes separately using

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations},style=myglossarystyle]
```

and

```
\printglossary[type=gene, title={List of Genes},style=myglossarystyle],
```

respectively.

When I first use an acronym it prints `single nucleotide polymorphism (SNP)`, however this doesn't work for the gene glossary. So the question is if I can make the glossary to act like a second list of acronyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\DefineAcronymSynonyms
\DeclareAcronymList{main}
\DeclareAcronymList{gene}
\newglossary{gene}{genin}{genout}{Index of Genes}
\newcommand{\newgene}[4][]{%
    \bgroup
    \def\acronymtype{gene}%
    \newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    \egroup
}%

\newacronym{SNP}{SNP}{single nucleotide polymorphism}
\newacronym{SNPa}{SNPa}{single nucleotide polymorphism}
\newgene{ApoE}{ApoE}{apolipoprotein E}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\gls{SNP}

\gls{SNP}

\gls{ApoE}

\gls{ApoE}

\acf{ApoE}


\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that works nicely, but comes with the disadvantage that it doesn't support the additional features of acronyms (like `\acf`, `\acs`...). Is there a way to support these as well?

Comment: I redid it, does it do what you want now?

Comment: It would be simpler just to define `\newgene` as `\newacronym[type=gene,#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}` rather than redefining `\acronymtype`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I guess I didn't read the documentation carefully enough, thanks. (The solution I had before was even more overcomplicated).